# How to export values from database into a string or char in C/C++ using SQLite?

Tags: c++, sql, c, database, sqlite

I have a Server/Client TCP server that can execute these tasks;
-When client sends LIST command to server, server lists all the connected clients with their ID and send this information back to client,
-Client sends an encrypted message and the ID of the client to the server
-Server receives the encrypted message, save it to the database as messages and send the message to other client
-The other client receives and decryptes the message

What i am trying to do;
-When client sends HISTORY command to the server, server should read the messages database insert these messages in a string or char array and send this string or char array to client over socket.

The problem is;
-When i try to select messages from database and write these values into a string using sqlite3_exec's callback function, it writes only one line to string everytime it runs and at the end of the callback function i have a string which includes only the last message from database.

The show history function is ;

```
void showHistory(){
    sqlite3* DB; 
    char* messaggeError; 
    int exit = 0; 

    exit = sqlite3_open("SERVER.db", &DB); 

    if (exit) { 
        cerr << "Error open DB " << sqlite3_errmsg(DB) << endl; 
    } 

    string sql("SELECT * FROM messageHistory");

    int exit3;
    exit3 = sqlite3_exec(DB, sql.c_str(), callBackHistory, 0, &messaggeError);



    if (exit3 != SQLITE_OK) { 
        cerr << "Error Insert" << endl; 
        sqlite3_free(messaggeError); 
    }
    sqlite3_close(DB);
}
```

The callback function is ;

```
int callBackHistory(void* data, int argc, char** argv, char** azColName) {
int i;
int offset = 0;
string s;

for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) { 

s += argv[i] + '\n' ;

} 

cout << "--->" << s << "<---" ;

return 0;
```

}

The output is ;

```
> --->1NTU1GRFNGU0RGU0RGU0RBRg==
<------>k=
<------>ZZRkZZRA==
<------>ZZRkZZRA==
<------>ZZRkZZRA==
<------>VFRQ==
<------>==
```

Here from the `*cout << "--->" << s << "<---" ;*` command in callback function the output shoul have been like this `*"--->message1(newline) message2 (newline) message3 (newline) ... <---"*`  but here the output is `*--->message1(newline)<--- --->message2(newline)<--- --->message3(newline)<---*`

and if i try to send it to client over socket, i can only send the message3 as the last line message of the database .

i hope the question can be understood well, any help would be useful, thank you so much :)

Comment: Don't use `sqlite3_exec()` if you want to do anything with the rows returned by a query; use a [prepared statement](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html).

Answer (score 0):

with using sqlite3_prepare and sqlite3_step functions i've solved the problem like this ;

```
void showHistory(int clientSocket){
sqlite3 *DB;
char *messaggeError;
int exit = 0;

exit = sqlite3_open("SERVER.db", &DB);

if (exit)
{
    cerr << "Error open DB " << sqlite3_errmsg(DB) << endl;
}

int exit3;

sqlite3_stmt *getMessages;
char* tblN;

 sqlite3_prepare(DB, "SELECT MESSAGE FROM messageHistory", -1, &getMessages, NULL);

 while (sqlite3_step(getMessages) == SQLITE_ROW)
{
    tblN = (char*)sqlite3_column_text(getMessages, 0);
    send(clientSocket, tblN, BUFFERSIZE, 0);
}

sqlite3_close(DB);}
```